# Can Not Edit Entity with TextProperty in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

i am using NBD Datastore to save some information that my application requires.Let's say i have a class like this:

```
class Example(db.Model):
    Entity1 = db.TextProperty()
    Entity2 = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
```

when i populate my db and i view it locally, i can see my update and even make changes (manually) to both the Entity1(TextProperty) and Entity2(StringProperty).

But when i deploy this app, and make an update and for some reasons, i want to change my values or update from the datastore viewer on appengine.google.com, only Entity2(StringProperty) becomes editable and for some reasons, i just can't change the value of  Entity1(TextProperty). Is there any  settings that i need to do to make this work ?

Answer (score 1):

The datastore viewer is just a convenience, it's not surprising only some entity types can be edited directly.

As you've seen, just a difference in model type changes the behavior. And the behavior on the development server is often different from the live system in any case.

**The simplest (only) solution is to *write code* that lets you perform the required edit on the model.**

Comment: or access the datastore using remote api